# 'Error: connecting slave requested to start from GTID 0-1-1, which is not in the master's binlog

Tags: mariadb-10.1

I have upgraded MariaDB from 10.1.38 to 10.1.41 version and parallelly in another branch to 10.2.18 to 10.2.26, which caused the below problem during the start of Database Replication. No other changes has been done regarding MariaDB installation

> Last_IO_Errno: 1236
> Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Error: connecting slave requested to start from GTID 0-1-1, which is not in the master's binlog. Since the master's binlog contains GTIDs with higher sequence numbers, it probably means that the slave has diverged due to executing extra erroneous transactions'

In earlier versions, it was working properly. Are there any changes went related to replication which we need to adapt explicitly during installation?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: 10.99.32.8
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3307
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-1-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 4
              Relay_Log_Space: 256
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Error: connecting slave requested to start from GTID 0-1-1, which is not in the master's binlog. Since the master's binlog contains GTIDs with higher sequence numbers, it probably means that the slave has diverged due to executing extra erroneous transactions'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 2
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                   Using_Gtid: Current_Pos
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 0-1-1
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
```

## Binary Log Detail

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show binlog events in 'binary-log.000001';
Log_name        Pos     Event_type      Server_id       End_log_pos     Info
binary-log.000001       4       Format_desc     1       256     Server ver: 10.2.26-MariaDB-log, Binlog ver: 4
binary-log.000001       256     Gtid_list       1       285     []
binary-log.000001       285     Binlog_checkpoint       1       329     binary-log.000001
binary-log.000001       329     Gtid    1       371     GTID 0-1-1
binary-log.000001       371     Query   1       473     create database if not exists test;
binary-log.000001       473     Stop    1       496
MariaDB [(none)]> show binlog events in 'binary-log.000002';
Log_name        Pos     Event_type      Server_id       End_log_pos     Info
binary-log.000002       4       Format_desc     1       256     Server ver: 10.2.26-MariaDB-log, Binlog ver: 4
binary-log.000002       256     Gtid_list       1       299     [0-1-1]
binary-log.000002       299     Binlog_checkpoint       1       343     binary-log.000002
binary-log.000002       343     Stop    1       366
MariaDB [(none)]> show binlog events in 'binary-log.000003';
Log_name        Pos     Event_type      Server_id       End_log_pos     Info
binary-log.000003       4       Format_desc     1       256     Server ver: 10.2.26-MariaDB-log, Binlog ver: 4
binary-log.000003       256     Gtid_list       1       299     [0-1-1]
binary-log.000003       299     Binlog_checkpoint       1       343     binary-log.000003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On analysis, able to find the above issue is due to the GTID difference between master and slave which made to create the below query.

MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20990

Stackoverflow: [Gtid Position difference between MariaDB version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556332/gtid-position-difference-between-mariadb-version)

With comments from MariaDB, we can see the GTID position 0-1-1 is changed with DDL transaction that occurred during Installation.

**Solved:** Added test DB for replication ignore with below property in my.cnf file

```
***binlog-ignore-db = test***
```